# Calling AngularJS controller function when html5 video ends

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video, html5-video, ionic-framework

I have a video on the homepage of my app which plays when I launch it. When the video ends I'd then like to use some CSS 3 transitions to move the page around.

```
<ion-view  hide-back-button="true" title="">
    <ion-pane>
        <div class="home-video">
            <video autoplay="autoplay" ng-click="ctrl.video()" aria-label="video of IBM logo" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" poster="images/Hero_Final_Placeholder.gif" onended="ctrl.video()">
                <source src="videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <img src="images/video_backup.gif" title="Your browser does not support the video tag.">
            </video>
        </div>
    </ion-pane>
</ion-view>
```

At the end of the video I'd like to be able to call an angularJS Controller function.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', ['ionic']).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
  controller: 'homeCtrl as ctrl'
}).state('project', {
  url: "/project/:projectId",
  templateUrl: 'views/project.html',
  controller: 'projectCtrl'
});

 // Default view to show
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');

}).run(function ($http, pouchDB, replicationService, $rootScope) {

  replicationService.replicate();

});
```

My controller looks like:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', false);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($rootScope){

this.data = {};

var ctrl = this;

    this.video = function () {

        console.log("video done");

    }

});
```

If I put a `console.log()` in the `<video onended="">` element it prints it out. If I try and call `ctrl.video()` which contains the same console.log I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: ctrl is not defined`

I know that ctrl is defined because if I add an `ng-click="ctrl.video()"` and I click the video player it prints out.

Comment: Did you find out what was the real issue/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angularjs HTML5 Video onended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090942/angularjs-html5-video-onended)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually what I did was use [Angular UI Utils](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/) which has a generic event binder. This allowed me to bind to an event that AngularJS doesn't out of the box. Using the following line `ui-event="{ ended : 'ctrl.video()'}"` I was able to call my function when the video ended which gave me the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit new to Angular, so I don't know the best way to fix it, but I can at least tell you why it isn't working.

`ng-click="ctrl.video()"` works because ctrl is defined in the controller's scope. All ng- attributes run within the controller's scope. But onended is a regular built-in HTML5 event handler attribute, so it runs in the global Javascript scope, not the controller's scope. There's no ctrl defined there.

(I'm not sure how `var ctrl = this;` causes ctrl to be defined in the controller's scope, but apparently it does. Still learning Angular...)