# Adding Javascript to an Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to add Javascript to a controller in Ionic. My JS syntax isn't quite right, can someone please give it a look over.

I assume JS has to be tagged to some form of scope for each block of code?

CONTROLLER

```
.controller('ProductCtrl', function(Products, $scope, $stateParams, $state, $timeout) {
    $scope.product = Products[$stateParams.productId];

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
    var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    function stopVideo(){
         video.pause();
         video.currentTime = 0;
    })

    var video = document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
       $state.go('app.home');
    })
```

PRODUCT.HTML

```
 <ion-view view-title="Individual Video">
 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
 <ion-content>
<h2>{{product.title}}</h2>
<h2>{{product.duration}}</h2>
<video id="myVideo" controls="controls" preload="metadata"  autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline"  class="videoPlayer"><source src="{{product.video}}" type="video/mp4" /></video>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: it's hard to understand what you are actually looking for

Comment: first you declare var video twice.. Second you declare a function stopVideo but bever use it. If it has to be used with binding in the template you have to store it in $scope like this  : $scope.stopVideo = function(){...}; . Thrid i don't even see the end bracket of the callback for $routeCHangeStartEvent. If you need more information please post the full content of the controller and the template where it's used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question. This might be helpful to you:

[Calling AngularJS controller function when html5 video ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963530/calling-angularjs-controller-function-when-html5-video-ends)

Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29030565/3298029